# Prestashop - Default VAT rate for visitors that are not connected

Tags: prestashop-1.7

I have set up a shop using Prestashop. I created a tax rule for my products and entered the VAT rates of all EU countries we sell to. When a user orders a product the VAT amount is calculated according to the address/country he entered in the checkout process, this works fine.

Unfortunately the VAT rate when the user is not connected is wrong. It should be 19% and not 17%, thus the products in the shop show wrong prices, e.g. 59,97 € instead of 60 €.

I haven't found out how the Prestashop frontend determines the VAT rate to be used to calculate the product price. There is no default VAT rate setting and the first rate in the table (lowest ID) has a VAT rate of 19%.

Does anybody know how that works ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can set default tax rule for each product, when editing a product in back office.

You have the ability to decide if a visitor/guest customer group should see the prices with/without
taxes applied by using the setting in Shop **Parameters > Customer Settings > Groups**
(there's a *"Price display method"* selector there).

If you want your visitor's context country being set without having them to actually enter an address,
you should enable native Geolocation (**International > Localization > Geolocation**).

Comment: The tax rule is set for each product and also configured for each EU country, that works. What I want to change is the rate of the default vat rate that is taken when the user is not connected.

Comment: The only way you have is to rely on geolocation, or develop a module that takes over the load of the page where you ask the customer "where are you from?" and then you set the Context::Country() aftewards.

Answer (score 0):

I found out how this works. Under International -> Localization you can set the store's default country. Set it to the country you like and the prices will be shown with the vat rate of that country if configured in the tax rules.